# Form input array is creating an empty array which !empty() won't work with

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form like so:

```
        <div class="clone-wrapper" data-id="education">
            <div class="row cloneable" data-id="0">             
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><?php echo System::translate("Education Institution Name"); ?></label>
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo System::translate("ex : University"); ?>" name="education[0][institution]" type="text" class="max_len" maxlength="100" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><?php echo System::translate("Education Degree"); ?></label>
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo System::translate("ex : Bachelor Degree"); ?>" name="education[0][degree]" type="text" class="max_len" maxlength="100" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><?php echo System::translate("Date of Enrollment"); ?></label>
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo System::translate("ex : January 2001"); ?>" name="education[0][year_begin]" type="text" class="monthyearpicker" autocomplete='off' value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><?php echo System::translate("Date of Completion"); ?></label>
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo System::translate("ex : December 2004"); ?>" name="education[0][year_finish]" type="text" class="monthyearpicker" autocomplete='off' value="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><?php echo System::translate("Education Note"); ?></label>
                            <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" name="education[0][about]"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="white-space-20"></div>
        <div class="row text-right">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm clonable-button" data-clone="education">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><?php echo System::translate("Add Education"); ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As you can see I am using name arrays like `education[0][inputname]` now my problem is this is creating an array with no values so I cannot check if they have not inputted values in to the inputs. It returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company] => 
            [title] => 
            [year_begin] => 
            [year_finish] => 
            [country] => 
            [notes] => 
        )

)
```

How can I make it return an empty array so I can use `!empty()` on?

Comment: Do you need `education[0][about]`?  You can just use `education[about]`etc..  Then `array_filter()`.

Comment: Yeah, there will be multiple of the same inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter out the empty elements and check:

```
if(empty(array_filter($_POST['education'][0]))) {
    // array is empty
}
```

If you need to check for any empty element, then:

```
if(count(array_filter($_POST['education'][0])) != count($_POST['education'][0])) {
    // one or more elements are empty
}
```